# Stripe create product and subscription fails on subscription payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

This is my use case:

Via my mobile app, a customer selects tangible products and a subscription.  They look like this:
// This is the product with a one-time charge

```
{
  // This is the product with a one-time charge 
        "productId": "prod_NkZSqunRlnno37",
        "priceId": "price_1Mz4mQGJv6dpZ3M5B7nxctaz",
        "price": 595,
        "requestedQty": 11
  }  ,

{
 // This is the product with a recurring charge 
        "productId": "prod_Njgo4ufuB9BsC3",
        "priceId": "price_1N6DEYGJv6dpZ3M5ZEyYfjGw",
        "price": 495,
    }
```

I want to charge them immediately for both.  Then, each month automatically charge them of the subscription (second item).

Here is what I am doing:

```
Customer customer = Customer.create(params);

long totalCharge = calculate();

 PaymentIntentCreateParams intentCreateParams = PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
                                        .setCustomer(customer.getId())
                                        .setAmount(totalCharge)
                                        .setCurrency("usd")
                                        .setDescription("PRODUCTS")
                                       .setSetupFutureUsage(SetupFutureUsage.OFF_SESSION)
                                       .setAutomaticPaymentMethods(
                                                        PaymentIntentCreateParams.AutomaticPaymentMethods.builder()
                                       .setEnabled(true)
                                       .build())
                                        .build();
 try {
   PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(intentCreateParams);
   SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentSettings subscriptionPaymentSettings =
                            SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentSettings
                                            .builder()
   .setSaveDefaultPaymentMethod(SaveDefaultPaymentMethod.ON_SUBSCRIPTION)
                                            .build();

            SubscriptionCreateParams subscriptionParams =
                            SubscriptionCreateParams
                                            .builder()
                                            .setCustomer(customer.getId())                                                     .addItem(SubscriptionCreateParams.Item.builder()                                                                                 .setPrice(subscriptionProduct.getPriceId())                                                                              .build() )                                                .setPaymentSettings(subscriptionPaymentSettings)                                                .setCollectionMethod(CollectionMethod.CHARGE_AUTOMATICALLY)                                                .setPaymentBehavior(SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentBehavior.DEFAULT_INCOMPLETE)                                                .addAllExpand(Arrays.asList("latest_invoice.payment_intent"))                                                
                                            .build();
    
 Subscription subscription = Subscription.create(subscriptionParams);
```

The paymentIntent is then returned to the mobile app where Stripe Elements submits with the collected paymentMethod.  In the Stripe dashboard I see two payments:

- PRODUCTS - this one is marked as succeeded as it has a payment method and customer
- Subscription creation - marked as incomplete. It has a customer (who also has an attached payment method) and that appears to have an incomplete subscription

I have a webhook event for "charge.succeeded" but when I retrieve that customer, it doesn't have any subscriptions.

I feel like I am making this too difficult, but despite repeated chats with Stripe Support, I am unable to get a payment method on that "subscription creation"

**Update based upon response:**
I created the customer and then try to create the subscription.  However, the subscription will not allow a one-time charge to be one of the items.  So I think this is why I have to create a subscription and an paymentIntent.

Comment: You said, "However, the subscription will not allow a one-time charge to be one of the items."  What does "not allow" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what's the error?  Are you sure you're specifying the one-time Price in the `add_invoice_items` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create both a Payment Intent and Subscription for this, all you need is the Subscription.

You can [add the one-time Price(s) to the Subscription's first Invoice using `add_invoice_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items):

> A list of prices and quantities that will generate invoice items appended to the next invoice for this subscription. You may pass up to 20 items.

Recurring Prices go in the `items` property of the Subscription.

You can then confirm [the Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent) the first Invoice of the Subscription generates in your mobile app.

Comment: Does this apply if I have tangible products as well as the subscription?

Comment: This approach will work with a mix of recurring and non-recurring Prices.  Not sure I understand what you mean by "tangible products"?  Tangible vs. what?

Comment: tangible being physical products with a one-time charge vs subscription with a recurring charge.  When I add tangible (non subscription) items to the subscription I get:  com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: The price specified is set to `type=one_time` but this field only accepts prices with `type=recurring`.; request-id: req_mCT6aaef5xKrvN

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to put all of the Prices, both recurring and non-recurring, in `items`.  That will not work.  You need to add the non-recurring items to the first Invoice only using `add_invoice_items` (which is separate from `items`) as outlined in my original answer.  Once you have the recurring Prices in `items` and the non-recurring Prices in `add_invoice_items` it should work as expected.

Comment: I see what you mean - I added items and additionalItems, then got the paymentIntent off the created subscription.  I now have a single payment entry for the amount of all the items and the subscription.  And my created patient has an active subscription.  Thank you!